# can I prove $ \lim_{n\to\infty} [a_0,a_1,a_2 \ldots] = \sqrt2 $ without proving convergence

Tags: proof-verification, convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

in order to prove that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} [a_0,a_1,a_2 \ldots] = \sqrt2 $$
where $a_0=1$ and $a_i=2$ for $ i \ge 1$

I assumed that $ \lim_{n\to\infty} [a_1,a_2 \ldots]$ converges and denoted it as $x$.

this gives out the solution pretty fast using the fact that
$x = 2 + \frac{1}{x} $

my question is , is it enough? or  do I actually need to prove convergent before I assume it?

I dont want to use the fact that a continued fraction converges if its periodic, I want to know if this argument is valid without knowing convergence

Comment: There's a standard result that all infinite continued fractions converge; in fact the difference between consecutive convergents is well-known, and approaches zero.  See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems).  What properties *do* you want to use?

Comment: No.  You can't assume it converges.  You must show it converges.  If you can show it converges, that's enough.  But you *must* show it converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that no, this is generally not enough. As an example, take the sequence defined by:

$$a_0=0\\a_{n+1}=1-a_n$$

This is just a fancy way of saying the sequence is $0,1,0,1,\dots$

For the classical notion of limits, this sequence does not have a limit and does not converge. However, if we were to use your approach and assume it converges to some limit $L$, we'd find that $L=1-L$, implying $L=\frac12$.

There are some different limit definitions which attempt to assign meaning to these values (much like there are different summation techniques which attempt to attach meaning to divergent series). **Under these definitions**, it is actually true $L=\frac12$ (which is not to say there can't be some other counter-example to your argument, even on that scenario). That said, for classical analysis this is simply flat-out wrong.

Comment: but there is a difference, because in this case, the sequences are different $0,1,0,1,\dots$ is not ths same sequence as $1,0,1,\dots$, where in my question we do actually have the exact same sequence. can this fact be used to justify my proof? cause I dont use $x_{n+1}$ and $ x_{n}$ which are different sequnces

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're saying. There is an underlying continued fraction sequence $f_n$ to your sequence $a_i$: $$f_n=[a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n]$$

In your question, you assumed $f_n$ converged (which is true) and found out the limit using that assumption. I showed that sometimes the assumption is wrong, and leads to wrong conclusions.

Comment: @DanielKatzan: What about $a = 1+2+4+8+\ldots$? Here we have $1+2a = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + \ldots = a$ and thus $a=-1$, but clearly the series $1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \ldots$ diverges under standard limit definition (and in particular, each partial sum is *farther away* from $-1$ than the previous one). In this case, the shape of the series is not changed at all by the operation.